# database connection checking in c++ program

Tags: c++, database, visual-studio, ocilib

I am trying to connect a database with the c++ program using OCILIB interface.
 my program is:-

```
  #include "ocilib.h"
 int main(int argc, char *args[])
 {
OCI_Connection *cn;
if (!OCI_Initialize(NULL, NULL, OCI_ENV_DEFAULT))
    cout << "connection failed";
cn = OCI_ConnectionCreate("db", "usr", "pwd", OCI_SESSION_DEFAULT);
if (cn != NULL)
{

    cout <<OCI_GetVersionServer(cn);
    cout <<"Server major version : %i\n"<< OCI_GetServerMajorVersion(cn);
    cout <<"Server minor version : %i\n"<<OCI_GetServerMinorVersion(cn);
    cout <<"Server revision version : %i\n"<< OCI_GetServerRevisionVersion(cn);
    cout <<"Connection version : %i\n"<< OCI_GetVersionConnection(cn);

    OCI_ConnectionFree(cn);
}
OCI_Cleanup();

 }
```

this code running in MSVisualstudio2015, I downloaded all OCI packages and set according to my environment..
i put linker path and additional include header files in project properties.
but when i building the application it shows.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Testdatabase, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>  Testing.cpp
1>Testing.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol OCI_Initialize 
 referenced in function main

1>Testing.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol OCI_Cleanup 
  referenced in function main

 1>Testing.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
 OCI_ConnectionCreate referenced in function main

 1>Testing.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
 OCI_ConnectionFree referenced in function main

 1>Testing.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
 OCI_GetVersionServer referenced in function main

 1>Testing.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
 OCI_GetServerMajorVersion referenced in function main

 1>Testing.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
 OCI_GetServerMinorVersion referenced in function main

 1>Testing.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
 OCI_GetServerRevisionVersion referenced in function main

 1>Testing.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
 OCI_GetVersionConnection referenced in function main

 1>c:\XXXXX\XXXXXX\documents\visual studio 
 2015\Projects\Testdatabase\x64\Debug\Testdatabase.exe : fatal error 
 LNK1120: 9 unresolved externals
 ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I read some documentations about this problem , but i am not able to solve this problem , give me any solution..

Comment: You have only added a path to the linker?

Comment: Configuration Properties->Linker->General->additional Library dependecies= my lib path,

Comment: Are there any extra additions to add my project properties?

Comment: You need to add oci.lib as Linker->Input->additional dependencies.

Comment: oh, now I added but i have another problem. I compiling successfully but i am not able to run the program... when i hit the debug button it shows and error is:-  **The code execution cannot proceed because ociliba.dll was not found reinstalling the program my fix this problem"**

Comment: Find it in your oracle sdk.

Comment: how, is there any procedure ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy ociliba.dll from the ocilib archive (under lib32|64 folder) to the folder where your executable is generated.